# XSLT Duplication need to be removed on the output

Tags: xslt

I have a filter.xsl and i am using this with my input xml, i am getting the output with the duplication. I need to remove the duplicate on the output. Could you please look at this and let me know where i need to changes?

This is the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns="http://www.gazettes.co.uk/assets/taxonomy"
  xmlns:tax="http://www.gazettes.co.uk/assets/taxonomy"
  xmlns:cc="http://www.tso.co.uk/assets/namespace/gazette/config"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <xsl:param name="privileges" as="node()" select="doc('privileges.xml')"/>

  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <notice-taxonomy>

      <xsl:apply-templates/>

      <xsl:if test="not(exists(/*[local-name() = 'notice-taxonomy']/*[local-name() = 'notice-type'][@level='category']))">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name() = 'notice-type'][@level='section']" mode="copy"/>
      </xsl:if>

    </notice-taxonomy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'notice-type'][@level='category']">
    <xsl:variable name="tree" select="."/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$privileges//privilege">



      <xsl:variable name="code" select="substring-after(.,':')"/>
<!-- <xsl:variable name="HHH"><xsl:sequence select="$code"/></xsl:variable> -->
      <xsl:if test="$code != ''">

          <xsl:if test="$tree//*[@code = $code]">
            <xsl:element name="notice-type">
              <xsl:copy-of select="$tree/@*"/>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="$tree" mode="copy"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:if>


      </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'notice-type'][@level='section']" mode="copy">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="localcode" select="@code"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$privileges//privilege">
      <xsl:variable name="pcode" select="substring-after(.,':')"/>
      <xsl:if test="$this//*[local-name() = 'notice-type'][@code = $pcode]">
        <xsl:element name="notice-type">
          <xsl:copy-of select="$this/@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$this/*" mode="copy"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'notice-type'][@level='notice']" mode="copy">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="localcode" select="@code"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$privileges//privilege">
      <xsl:variable name="pcode" select="substring-after(.,':')"/>
      <xsl:if test="$localcode = $pcode">
        <xsl:element name="notice-type">
          <xsl:copy-of select="$this/@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notice-taxonomy xmlns="http://www.gazettes.co.uk/assets/taxonomy">
   <notice-type name="State" code="11" service-key="all-notices" level="category" sort="01"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="Proclamations" code="1101" level="notice" sort="01"/>
   </notice-type>
   `<notice-type name="Corporate Insolvency" code="24" service-key="insolvency" level="category"
                sort="15"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="General" code="2400/0" level="section" sort="01">
         <notice-type name="Moratoria, Prohibited Names and Other: Moratorium: Coming to an End"
                      code="2402"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="02"/>
         <notice-type name="Court Petitions and Orders: Cross-border Insolvencies" code="2404"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="04"/>
      </notice-type>
      <notice-type name="General" code="2400/0" level="section" sort="01">
         <notice-type name="Moratoria, Prohibited Names and Other: Moratorium: Coming to an End"
                      code="2402"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="02"/>
         <notice-type name="Court Petitions and Orders: Cross-border Insolvencies" code="2404"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="04"/>
      </notice-type>
      <notice-type name="Administration" code="2400/1" level="section" sort="02">
         <notice-type name="Notices to Members" code="2413" level="notice" sort="13"/>
      </notice-type>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Corporate Insolvency" code="24" service-key="insolvency" level="category"
                sort="15"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="General" code="2400/0" level="section" sort="01">
         <notice-type name="Moratoria, Prohibited Names and Other: Moratorium: Coming to an End"
                      code="2402"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="02"/>
         <notice-type name="Court Petitions and Orders: Cross-border Insolvencies" code="2404"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="04"/>
      </notice-type>
      <notice-type name="General" code="2400/0" level="section" sort="01">
         <notice-type name="Moratoria, Prohibited Names and Other: Moratorium: Coming to an End"
                      code="2402"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="02"/>
         <notice-type name="Court Petitions and Orders: Cross-border Insolvencies" code="2404"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="04"/>
      </notice-type>
      <notice-type name="Administration" code="2400/1" level="section" sort="02">
         <notice-type name="Notices to Members" code="2413" level="notice" sort="13"/>
      </notice-type>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Corporate Insolvency" code="24" service-key="insolvency" level="category"
                sort="15"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="General" code="2400/0" level="section" sort="01">
         <notice-type name="Moratoria, Prohibited Names and Other: Moratorium: Coming to an End"
                      code="2402"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="02"/>
         <notice-type name="Court Petitions and Orders: Cross-border Insolvencies" code="2404"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="04"/>
      </notice-type>
      <notice-type name="General" code="2400/0" level="section" sort="01">
         <notice-type name="Moratoria, Prohibited Names and Other: Moratorium: Coming to an End"
                      code="2402"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="02"/>
         <notice-type name="Court Petitions and Orders: Cross-border Insolvencies" code="2404"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="04"/>
      </notice-type>
      <notice-type name="Administration" code="2400/1" level="section" sort="02">
         <notice-type name="Notices to Members" code="2413" level="notice" sort="13"/>
      </notice-type>
   </notice-type>`
   <notice-type name="Personal Insolvency" code="25" service-key="insolvency" level="category"
                sort="16"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="Statutory Demands" code="2501" level="notice" sort="01"/>
      <notice-type name="Administration Order" code="2505" level="notice" sort="05"/>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Personal Insolvency" code="25" service-key="insolvency" level="category"
                sort="16"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="Statutory Demands" code="2501" level="notice" sort="01"/>
      <notice-type name="Administration Order" code="2505" level="notice" sort="05"/>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Societies Regulation" code="28" service-key="all-notices"
                level="category"
                sort="19">
      <notice-type name="Building Societies" code="2803" level="notice" sort="03"/>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Personal Legal" code="29" service-key="wills-and-probate"
                level="category"
                sort="20"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="Deceased Estates" code="2903" level="notice" sort="03"/>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Contributors Information" code="99" service-key="all-notices"
                level="category"
                sort="0">
      <notice-type name="Contributors Information" code="9900" level="notice" sort="01"/>
   </notice-type>
</notice-taxonomy>
```

and this should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notice-taxonomy xmlns="http://www.gazettes.co.uk/assets/taxonomy">
   <notice-type name="State" code="11" service-key="all-notices" level="category" sort="01"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="Proclamations" code="1101" level="notice" sort="01"/>
   </notice-type>

   <notice-type name="Corporate Insolvency" code="24" service-key="insolvency" level="category"
                sort="15"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="General" code="2400/0" level="section" sort="01">
         <notice-type name="Moratoria, Prohibited Names and Other: Moratorium: Coming to an End"
                      code="2402"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="02"/>
         <notice-type name="Court Petitions and Orders: Cross-border Insolvencies" code="2404"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="04"/>
      </notice-type>
      <notice-type name="General" code="2400/0" level="section" sort="01">
         <notice-type name="Moratoria, Prohibited Names and Other: Moratorium: Coming to an End"
                      code="2402"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="02"/>
         <notice-type name="Court Petitions and Orders: Cross-border Insolvencies" code="2404"
                      level="notice"
                      sort="04"/>
      </notice-type>
      <notice-type name="Administration" code="2400/1" level="section" sort="02">
         <notice-type name="Notices to Members" code="2413" level="notice" sort="13"/>
      </notice-type>
   </notice-type>

   <notice-type name="Personal Insolvency" code="25" service-key="insolvency" level="category"
                sort="16"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="Statutory Demands" code="2501" level="notice" sort="01"/>
      <notice-type name="Administration Order" code="2505" level="notice" sort="05"/>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Personal Insolvency" code="25" service-key="insolvency" level="category"
                sort="16"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="Statutory Demands" code="2501" level="notice" sort="01"/>
      <notice-type name="Administration Order" code="2505" level="notice" sort="05"/>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Societies Regulation" code="28" service-key="all-notices"
                level="category"
                sort="19">
      <notice-type name="Building Societies" code="2803" level="notice" sort="03"/>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Personal Legal" code="29" service-key="wills-and-probate"
                level="category"
                sort="20"
                popular="true">
      <notice-type name="Deceased Estates" code="2903" level="notice" sort="03"/>
   </notice-type>
   <notice-type name="Contributors Information" code="99" service-key="all-notices"
                level="category"
                sort="0">
      <notice-type name="Contributors Information" code="9900" level="notice" sort="01"/>
   </notice-type>
</notice-taxonomy>
```

and the param preveliges.xml

```
<privileges>
            <privilege>Access my notices</privilege>
            <privilege>Access draft notices</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice</privilege>
            <privilege>Access published notices</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2903</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2413</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2803</privilege>
            <privilege>Access pending notices</privilege>
            <privilege>Access my account</privilege>
            <privilege>Place legacy notice</privilege>
            <privilege>Access my searches</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:1101</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2404</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2402</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2501</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:2505</privilege>
            <privilege>Place notice of type:9900</privilege>
</privileges>
```

Any help, pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elimination of duplicates generally goes under the name "grouping": if you look up "grouping" in your favourite XSLT reference book, you'll find lots of information. The technique depends on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, which you haven't told us. In XSLT 2.0 there's a special instruction, xsl:for-each-group, which makes it easy. In XSLT 1.0 there's a coding technique called "Muenchian grouping", which you'll need to read up.